# GitHub API: Get email addresses of all members of organization

Tags: github, github-api

GitHub [API](http://developer.github.com/v3/) provides a way to get the [members](http://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/) of an organization. I am the admin/owner for my organization and I would like to get the email addresses of all the users. I tried with the `members` API but it does not return the email addresses.

Using curl with my admin `auth-token`:

```
GET /orgs/my-org/members
```

I get the response that look like this (for one of the users):

```
"login": "auny",
    "id": some-number,
    "avatar_url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/6579d09c459f1adad8a60463f47eadd3?d=https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com%2Fimages%2Fgravatars%2Fgravatar-user-420.png",
    "gravatar_id": "6579d09c459f1adad8a60463f47eadd3",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/auny",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/auny",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/auny/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/auny/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/auny/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/auny/starred{/owner} 
     {/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/auny/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/auny/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/auny/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/auny/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": 
    "https://api.github.com/users/auny/received_events",
    "type": "User"
```

Strangely enough, this contains a wealth of information about the user but not one of the important ones i.e the email address of the user. Being the `admin` I should be able to get the email address's of all my users.

The other [user API](http://developer.github.com/v3/users/emails/) only return my own email address i.e the email address of the account whose `auth-token` is used in the request. API usage:

```
GET /user/emails
```

How can this be achieved? Is there way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fetching the list of org members, fetch the info for each member using [this API endpoint](http://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user):

```
/users/:user
```

This will return the e-mail address of the user you have specified in your request URL.

Comment: This endpoint returns `email` field only for certain users and that too is set to `null`. For most of the users however, the `email` field is not even present. Could this be related to how the users have configured their accounts?

Comment: Yep, it is possible that some users don't have an e-mail address defined in https://github.com/settings/profile and that causes the email field in the API response to be blank. Nothing you can do about that but nag the users in your org to set their e-mail :).

Comment: There should be at least one `email` address with which the user is registered on github or a member of an organization on github. I was hoping for that `email` to be returned.

Comment: The suggestion about telling the user in my org to set their emails is not feasible because I am making an app to be distributed and I cannot ask the users of the org that uses my app to do so

Comment: Ivan, if you are a github-dev, then I would like to file this as a feature request for the next releases. Getting the email address of all the users of an organization is an important feature for the admin of that organization

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a GitHub dev, but I have tried what I described in my previous comment. If you go to your account settings - you will see the e-mail address you used when signing up. You may then remove that e-mail address and after that API calls will no longer return anything under "email". It does sound strange a bit, but that's what you get currently. I suggest you e-mail the GitHub support team at support@github.com and describe your feature request and reasoning for it.

Comment: Wait, this answer is only for one member at a time. OP wanted all of them.

Comment: @KevinSuttle Currently, there's no endpoint in the GitHub API which would give you that information in a single response.

Comment: I'd settle for 1 at at time. But the fact that it might not return an email for a person in my org is ridiculous.

It's bad enough that Github doesn't allow companies to enforce 2FA, but trying to audit and nag users is impossible to do too. It's like Github doesn't want businesses to secure their users Github accounts.

Comment: I added an option to query all emails that match the verified and approved domains of your organization: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77572694/736079

Answer (score 11):

Using [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/), you don't have to call a request per user. The following will get members of an organization with their `email` (if provided in public profile) :

```graphql
{
  organization(login: "my-org") {
    membersWithRole(first: 100) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          login
          name
          email
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20organization%28login%3A%20%22my-org%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20membersWithRole%28first%3A%20100%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20login%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20email%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20pageInfo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20endCursor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hasNextPage%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

*[edit 08/2020]* Using `membersWithRole` instead of deprecated `members` field

Comment: Organization members is now a deprecated field. Instead, use memberStatuses.

Comment: "You must provide a `first` or `last` value to properly paginate the `forks` connection."

Comment: For those reading in 2023, `email` field only gives you the public email which is most of the time empty.

Answer (score 4):

You can use git repository instead! There are plenty of interesting information inside.

Try to run:

```
git shortlog -s -n -e
```

You will see the list of committers with email address.

Comment: This does not suffice to correlate emails with GitHub usernames. It also doesn’t suffice for organization members who have not committed to a particular repository.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to this, as I just needed it, if you need more than 100 results (e.g. using the gh cli option `--paginate`) the query can be amended as:

```
query($endCursor: String) {
  organization(login: "LOGIN") {
    samlIdentityProvider {
      ssoUrl
      externalIdentities(first: 100, after: $endCursor) {
        pageInfo {
          hasNextPage
          endCursor
        }
        edges {
          node {
            guid
            samlIdentity {
              nameId
            }
            user {
              login
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this to get the email used by your identity provider (IdP) i.e. for SAML, see [osowskit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50614349/361842).

Org example below; but see the above link for more info & an example for auth at enterprise level:

```
query {
  organization(login: "LOGIN") {
    samlIdentityProvider {
      ssoUrl
      externalIdentities(first: 100) {
        edges {
          node {
            guid
            samlIdentity {
              nameId
            }
            user {
              login
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of places where email fields are stored and depending on your level of access you might be able to list them.

1. Public email
2. SAML identity (enterprise)
3. Verified domain email (enterprise)
4. License assignment (enterprise)

## 1. public email

If the user has a public email configured for their account and made it discoverable, [you can query this public email address here using the following query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47519077/736079):

```
gh api graphql --paginate -f query='{
  organization(login: "my-org") {
    membersWithRole(first: 100, after: $endCursor) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          login
          name
          email
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

## 2. SAML identity

If your organization has SAML SSO or OIDC-Connect enabled, [you can query the logon email address through the following query:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76127774/736079)

```
gh api graphql --paginate -f query='query {
  organization(login: "YOUR_ORG") {
    samlIdentityProvider {
      ssoUrl
      externalIdentities(first: 100, after: $endCursor) {
        edges {
          node {
            guid
            samlIdentity {
              nameId
              emails {
                primary
                type
                value
              }
            }
            user {
              login
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## 3. Verified domain email

If you are the administrator of a GitHub organization, you get access to [the email addresses that match your verified domains using the following query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71031517/get-github-users-emails-for-verified-organization-through-api):

```
gh api graphql --paginate -f query='query {
  organization(login: "YOUR_ORG") {
    membersWithRole (first: 100, after: $endCursor){
      edges {
          node {
            login
            organizationVerifiedDomainEmails(login: "YOUR_ORG")
          }
        }
    }
  }
}'
```

## 4. License Assignment

You can also [request the details of all people in your enterprise who were assigned a license](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/rest/enterprise-admin/license?apiVersion=2022-11-28):

```
GET https://api.github.com/enterprises/{enterprise}/consumed-licenses
```

It returns the verified domain emails as well.