# Access linked SAML identity via the GitHub API

Tags: github, saml, github-api

I'd like to get a mapping between GitHub logins and emails in my organization using the GitHub API (any version).

I can get the emails on organization members' accounts with this GraphQL query:

```
query { 
  organization(login:"myorg"){
    members(first:100) {
      nodes {
        login
        name
        email
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this isn't the email I'm after. I really want the email on the "Linked SSO identity", which I get to from my organization page by clicking this link:

[image: SAML identity linked link]

When I click this link, the desired email is listed in several places on https://github.com/orgs/myorg/people/danvk/sso.

Is it possible to access this SSO-linked email via any version of the GitHub API?

Comment: I believe this query works for SCIM provisioned accounts https://github.com/github/platform-samples/issues/168

Comment: Thanks @osowskit! If you'd like to post that GraphQL query in an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Organisation Level SAML

You can access this information for accounts provisioned via SCIM*.

```
query {
  organization(login: "LOGIN") {
    samlIdentityProvider {
      ssoUrl
      externalIdentities(first: 100) {
        edges {
          node {
            guid
            samlIdentity {
              nameId
            }
            user {
              login
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[authored by a member of GitHub's support staff] and samples available [here](https://github.com/github/platform-samples/issues/168).

- I haven't verified if accounts that have linked SAML accounts outside of SCIM would work using this query.

### Enterprise Level SAML

If your IdP's configured at the enterprise level, run instead:

```
{
  enterprise(slug: "MYENTERPRISENAME") {
    ownerInfo {
      samlIdentityProvider {
        externalIdentities(after: null, first: 100) {
          pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
            endCursor
          }
          edges {
            node {
              user {
                login
              }
              samlIdentity {
                nameId
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Additional Info

These GraphQL queries can be run via the GitHub CLI ([download here](https://cli.github.com/)).

Permissions are provided by a personal access token (PAT).  You can set this up at https://github.com/settings/tokens.

- If querying the org, you'll need to assign your PAT the `admin:org` right.  You'll also need to authorise it for each org against which you intend to use it (via the `Configure SSO` option next to the PAT.
- If querying the enterprise, you'll need to assign your PAT the `admin:enterprise` right.

To authenticate create an environment variable, `GH_TOKEN`, and set its value to the token's value (if you didn't note this when creating the token, you'll have to drop and recreate the token to get a fresh value).

Examples of how to use the `gh` cli to run graphql (and other API) queries can be found here: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api

Comment: I have confirmed that the `samlIdentityProvider` query works even if SCIM is not in place.

Answer (score 3):

this worked for what i needed:

```
query {
  user(login: "SOME-USER"){
    organizationVerifiedDomainEmails(login: "SOME-ORG")
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.