# List out GitHub Organization Members UserName and Email to CSV/Excel

Tags: github

Is there a way to export the list of GitHub Organization Members UserName and Email in csv or excel. I need to get the list to clean up users who no longer using the repositories.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77572694/736079

Answer (score 1):

Go to `https://github.com/orgs/<your-organization>/people`, click the Export drop down, and choose CSV.

[image: Export drop down menu]

[This feature was added in October 2021](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-10-06-export-organization-members/).

[Further documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-membership-in-your-organization/exporting-member-information-for-your-organization).

Answer (score 0):

GitHub doesn't provide an export functionality for organization members, but this can be easily scripted using a language like Ruby and the API.  The REST API provides a [paginated endpoint to list members](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/orgs#list-organization-members), which you can call incrementally to get all the members, and then emit to a CSV format from your script.