# get Github users' emails for verified organization through API

Tags: github, github-api

So, I am an administrator of my Github org. I have verified the domain in my organization, @mycompany.com.

My users sign up for the organization using the corporate email, @mycompany.com

For example, john@mycompany.com

Since my organization has an authorized domain, as an administrator - I can see users' emails in the Github UI (only for the verified domain), even if users set the emails to private.

How do I achieve the same through the API?

Comment: In certain, I can see their emails in https://github.com/orgs/mycompany/people/john, but this endpoint doesn't seem to be exposed in the API

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub API: Get email addresses of all members of organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299026/github-api-get-email-addresses-of-all-members-of-organization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case you're still searching, you can use the `organizationVerifiedDomainEmails` field in GitHub's [GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#:%7E:text=organizationVerifiedDomainEmails) *- edit (11th Oct '22) - for those on the Enterprise Plan only (see reply below).*

Example query here:

```
query getRepoMembers($repo: String!, $owner: String!) {
  repository(name: $repo, owner: $owner) {
    collaborators {
      edges {
        permission
        node {
          login
          name
          organizationVerifiedDomainEmails(login: $owner)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `organizationVerifiedDomainEmails` field does not show any emails for me (an owner) on github.com. I think it is enterprise plan only.

Comment: Ah... That is likely the case. We had just jumped onto the Enterprise plan before I had replied to this.

I'll update my answer to avoid getting anyone's hopes up.

Comment: Yeah, my problem was that this is only exposed through GraphQL API, where I was building my thing on top of REST API, to my surprise they are not fully intersecting in the functionality they provide. 

Thanks for the reply anyways.