# Access the private email of the organization members inside a custom action using GitHub PAT

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I was trying to access the private email of organization members inside a custom action using GitHub Personal Access Token(PAT).
The PAT is from the enterprise owner and has all the necessary scopes to access all the organizations and repositories under that. Tried with GitHub GraphQL API but it is only able to fetch the public mail, does not work for private mails. Any possible solutions?

Comment: Does this thread answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299026/github-api-get-email-addresses-of-all-members-of-organization? Or did you try it and observed it only returned public email addresses?

Comment: What does your GraphQL query look like?

Comment: The link is below, but only allows public emails. How can access the private emails of my organization members, is there any method to achieve so? https://gist.github.com/SaurabhRai19/49189ae4f12db2fd60d2200017136929