# GitHub API and Email Adddresses

Tags: github, github-api

Im trying to pull the email addresses for all users within my org.
My GraphQL query looks like this:

```
{
  organization(login: "####") {
    membersWithRole(first: 100) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          login
          name
          email
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, it only shows the email if the user has made it publicly shown. The reason I need this is to remove users from my org that have left/cancelled.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

> it only shows the email if the user has made it publicly shown.

Yes, which means that private emails are not to be queried or, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299026/github-api-get-email-addresses-of-all-members-of-organization#comment25096292_17301595):

> some users don't have an e-mail address defined in `github.com/settings/profile` and that causes the email field in the API response to be blank.

As [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71911469/6309), using email alone won't work, since private emails would not be part of that kind of queries.

That can give you a [User node is null if email is private or unset](https://github.community/t/user-node-is-null-if-email-is-private-or-unset/179323).

An other approach would be needed in your case, like, for instance, [Get last activity for a user in an organisation GitHub Ecosystem](https://github.community/t/graphql-github-v4-api-get-last-activity-for-a-user-in-an-organisation/14415/5).

Comment: Not sure if the last activity approach will work. But thanks for the response.