# Export Github Enterprise/Organization member email addresses via API

Tags: api, github, member, enterprise

It is possible for an enterprise admin to export enterprise member information

https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/admin/user-management/managing-users-in-your-enterprise/exporting-membership-information-for-your-enterprise

This export provides the email address used to register each member account

Is it possible to perform this export via an API? Perhaps the enterprise API?

I know it is possible to export members of an Organization via the API by iterating over the response from

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/orgs/members?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-organization-members

but I can't find anywhere in this API that actually provides a member -> registered email mapping

I know it is possible to export members of an Organization via the API by iterating over the response from

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/orgs/members?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-organization-members

but I can't find anywhere in this API that actually provides a member -> registered email mapping

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub API: Get email addresses of all members of organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299026/github-api-get-email-addresses-of-all-members-of-organization)